# How to pass tab id to form action

Tags: php, codeigniter, tabs

I have to pass the id of selected tab when another action occurs

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li  <?php if($all_index== 1){?> class="active" <?}?> ><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
            <li  <?php if($select_index== 1){?> class="active" <?}?>><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Selected</a></li>
            <li  <?php if($reject_index== 1){?> class="active" <?}?> ><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Rejected</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I have a dropdown to filter the tab data..First tab is always active.

If i want to filter the second tab,then i click the dropdown the action occur..but the tab selected is first one..I  want the Second one

Comment: unclear , requires more info with codes you tried..

Comment: You need to provide more info

Comment: I want to pass the tab id through the form action

Comment: you want to send value on form submit??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to capture the value on form submit, create a hidden field in your form. So every time on click, capture the id of the tab and store in hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" id-"hidden" name="tab-selected" />
```

In script

```
$(document).on("click","#myTab a",function() {
    var sel = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#hidden").val(sel);
});
```

so on form post, you will get the selected tab's value.

Here is the fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X4WtG/112/)

Answer (score 0):

In **View**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li  <?php if($tab_index== 1){?> class="active" <?}?> ><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Controller/FunctionName/1" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
    <li  <?php if($tab_index== 2){?> class="active" <?}?>><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Controller/FunctionName/2" data-toggle="tab">Selected</a></li>
    <li  <?php if($tab_index== 3){?> class="active" <?}?> ><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Controller/FunctionName/3" data-toggle="tab">Rejected</a></li>
</ul>
```

in **Controller**

```
public function FunctionName($value)
{
    # code...

    // pass which id should be active alone with data
}
```

Comment: Can i make any other changes?

Comment: <div class="tab-pane <?php if($tab_index== 1) { ?> active <?php } ?>" id="tab_1_1">

Comment: try it and see. Cz i cant guess this